# Как сериализовать JSON, если поле заранее неизвестно?

Tags: java, android, json

Приходит Json примерно вот такого вида. Вопрос следующий, если название поля массива заранее неизвестно (оно непостоянное и будет меняться каждый раз), как мне его правильно сериализовать, чтобы потом к нему обращаться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: видимо придется get(0) и дальше сериализовать массив данных

Comment: @SeniorPomidor неизвестно будет только название массива, сами же элементы массива будут точно такого же вида.

Comment: @ВитяМинашкин, возможно вот эта либа будет полезна: https://github.com/afollestad/ason

Comment: вот поэтому и говорю. ты получаешь этот первый элемент, который вернет тебе JSONArray,  а дальше эот JSONArray серилизуешь

Comment: @SeniorPomidor я использую Retrofit2 для запроса и в ответ получаю уже сирилизованный объект Pojo

Comment: **Де**сериализовать. Десериализовать как обычную мапу, после чего просканить ее ключи.

Comment: @ВитяМинашкин в Retrofit можно применить свой конвертер, в котором сделать десериализацию как угодно, к примеру так, как Вам советует Senior Pomidor

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял поле которое вы хотите сериализовать является id объекта cart, так вот, это не совсем правильно передавать json в таком виде. Если вы можете изменит формат отправляемого json объекта сделайте лучше так:

```
{"cart":{
   "cart_id":"588a141cf2633f057d4f47e8",
   "categories":[
    {"count":"1",
      "form":{
       "title":".....",
       "price":"200"   
       },
       "variations":"",
       "category_id":"......",
       "image":null
    },{"count":"1",
      "form":{
       "title":".....",
       "price":"200"   
       },
       "variations":"",
       "category_id":"......",
       "image":null
    }
    ]
}
}
```